# It won't boot from the USB

Tags: usb

Ubuntu won't boot from USB I have restarted it, turned it off and on again, I help F12, F10, F2, and ESC and nothing is happening.

Comment: Can you dig a little deeper and provide more information? How did you create the installation media? Are you sure it's valid?  When you review the documentation for your device, what key are you advised to press to edit BIOS/firmware settings?

Comment: Some bios have booting from USB disabled, will need to check that it is enabled.